# cPanel Apache empty response after 60 seconds

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, varnish

I'm currently trying to increase the maximum execution time of a PHP script and I can't figure out why Apache is always returning an empty response after 60 seconds.

I have already increased the maximum execution time of PHP, the maximum post size and the maximum upload size. I have verified the Tweak settings and the Apache settings to see if there were something related to maximum execution time of maximum request time or timeout... Can't find anything.

Maybe the problem is related to the memory usage or something else but I can't figure it out.

I have a third party module that is Varnish and when I try to do my request using Varnish, everything works fine. Otherwise, if I disable it (it is currently disabled), apache can't return me a response. I get this from Google chrome :

**No data received
Error code: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

The PHP script is this one :

```
<?php

    $timeInSeconds = 70;

    $start = microtime(true);
    $end = $start + $timeInSeconds;
    $diff = $end - $start;
    echo 'start: '.$start.'<br />';
    while ($start < $end)
    {
            $start = microtime(true);
    }
    echo 'end: '.$end.'<br />';
    echo 'difference: '.$diff;
```

Using the command line, everything is working.

Comment: Error logs say nothing. That is really strange. There is only 1 entry in access_log which is the GET request I do.

Comment: It's a cPanel/WHM server that I manage. Dedicated server.

Comment: if hosted on shared host some times they kill scripts running longer than X

Comment: It's a dedicated server that I own. I'm the administrator. I try to configure it to allow me executing (over apache) a php script longer than 60 seconds.

Comment: well then im out if ideas, sorry ;(

Comment: Have you tried set_time_limit(0); ?

Comment: What about [TimeOut](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **WHM >> Service Manager >> Apache Configuration >> Global Configuration** (I don't know the right menu names because my WHM is on portuguese) and change Timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check it with the following script
this will flush the output buffer to the screen while stil running

```
<?php

$timeInSeconds = 70;

$start = microtime(true);
$end = $start + $timeInSeconds;
$diff = $end - $start;
echo 'start: '.$start.'<br />';
while ($start < $end)
{
    $start = microtime(true);
    echo $start;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'end: '.$end.'<br />';
echo 'difference: '.$diff;
```

for more information about flush:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php